# Matlab: Mix Input vector

Tags: matlab, vector

Hey there,
is there any way to 'mix up' the order of the elements of an input vector in matlab randomly? Say I input

[1:5]'

I wanna get out for example:

[3 5 1 2 4]'

thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [RANDPERM](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/randperm.html):

```
shuffledOutput = inputVector(randperm(length(inputVector)));
```